# Problem with If else statement within For Next loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to put a validation when inserting a data on the database. I have a combobox = cbox_status, a qtyorder column and qtyreceived column on my datagridview = dgvAddMRR. What im trying to do is that, when cbox_status = Received - Lacking and all row on column qtyorder = all row on column qtyreceived, it should notify to change the cbox_status to Received - Complete. But, when cbox_status = Received - Complete and some row on column qtyorder = some row on column qtyreceived And some row on column qtyorder != some row on column qtyreceived, it should notify me to change cbox_status to Received - Lacking. My problem on my code, is that it proceeds to inserting data on the database even if cbox_status = Received - complete, some rows qtyorder = qtyreceived and some rows qtyorder != qtyreceived which is wrong because it should notify me to change the cbox_status to Received - Lacking. I hope you understand my problem. Please help me.

Here is my code. . .

```
Private Sub btn_done_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_done.Click
    If tb_mrrno.Text = "" Or tb_pono.Text = "" Or tb_requestedby.Text = "" Or tb_intendedfor.Text = "" Or tb_purpose.Text = "" Or tb_suppliers.Text = "" Or tb_supplierdrno.Text = "" Or cbox_status.Text = "" Or dgvAddMRR.RowCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please fill all necessary fields including selecting an Item.", MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Else
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvAddMRR.Rows
            Dim qtyorder As Double = row.Cells("qtyorder").Value.ToString
            Dim qtyreceived As Double = row.Cells("qtyreceived").Value.ToString
            Dim balance As Double = row.Cells("balance").Value.ToString


            If qtyorder.ToString > qtyreceived.ToString And cbox_status.Text = "Received - Complete" Then
                MsgBox("On Status, please select Received - Lacking to proceed.", MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            ElseIf (cbox_status.Text = "Received - Lacking") And (qtyorder.ToString = qtyreceived.ToString) Then
                MsgBox("On Status, please select Received - Complete to proceed.", MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            End If

            If qtyorder.ToString > qtyreceived.ToString And cbox_status.Text = "Received - Lacking" Then
                InsertMRR_newave()
            End If
            If (cbox_status.Text = "Received - Complete") And (qtyorder.ToString = qtyreceived.ToString) Then
                InsertMRR_newave()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I stopped reading at `Dim qtyorder As Double = row.Cells("qtyorder").Value.ToString`. Set `Option Strict On`, fix the errors and maybe it'll work as intended.

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are two different languages and the tag descriptions explicitly state not to use each for the other, yet you used both anyway.

Comment: @Jimi how to set Option Strict On?

Comment: Forever (recommended): `Tools → Option → Projects and Solutions → VB Defaults`. At Project level: `Project → Properties → Compile`. Set all Options (`Explicit`, `Strict` and `Infer`) to `On`. When you look at your code, after that, don't think you have a problem; you have just found the solution. You just need to fix the mistakes that were already there but hidden from you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be with comparing strings using >. Try another option, maybe look into StrComp (https://www.educba.com/vba-string-comparison/), Or InStr.

The link below is Microsoft's explanation of how strings compare with =,>,< operators. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/comparison-operators

Using the > provides interesting results when used with strings.
Assuming these values were declared or converted to string...

"73" < "9"

' The result of the preceding comparison is True.

Hope this points you in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Changed each of the Or in the first If statement to OrElse because it will short circuit the line as soon as it hits a True condition instead of evaluating each condition.

You are mixing MessageBox and MsgBox. I changed it to the more portable MessageBox.

You needed Exit Sub so your code won't continue after the MessageBox. The code continuing will eventually insert the data.

As Option Strict will tell you get rid of the .ToString. You don't seem to be using balance.

Why not just reset the combo box in code instead of having the user do it. Otherwise you will need more Exit Subs.

I added a parameter to InsertMRR_newave(row). This would be necessary if you are using this method to update the database row by row.

If InsertMRR_newave is using a data adapter with the .Update method it shouldn't be called until after the for loop.

```
Private Sub btn_done_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_done.Click
    If tb_mrrno.Text = "" OrElse tb_pono.Text = "" OrElse tb_requestedby.Text = "" OrElse tb_intendedfor.Text = "" OrElse tb_purpose.Text = "" OrElse tb_suppliers.Text = "" OrElse tb_supplierdrno.Text = "" OrElse cbox_status.Text = "" OrElse dgvAddMRR.RowCount = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill all necessary fields including selecting an Item.", "Missing Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvAddMRR.Rows
        Dim qtyorder As Double = CDbl(row.Cells("qtyorder").Value)
        Dim qtyreceived As Double = CDbl(row.Cells("qtyreceived").Value)
        'Dim balance As Double = CDbl(row.Cells("balance").Value)
        If qtyorder > qtyrecieved Then
            row.Cells(ComboBoxColumnName.Index).Value = "Received - Lacking"
        Else
            row.Cells(ComboBoxColumnName.Index).Value = "Received - Complete"
        End If
        InsertMRR_newave(row)
    Next
End Sub
```